# Make underbraces span over particular array columns

Tags: multicolumn, arrays, underbrace

I'm new to using latex and I tried to look at some related questions here, but unfortunately I didn't understand how to apply suggested solutions to my problem yet.

So I got this .tex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro \usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\red{\colorbox{red!80}{\color{red!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\yellow{\colorbox{yellow!80}{\color{yellow!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\green{\colorbox{green!80}{\color{green!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\blue{\colorbox{blue!80}{\color{blue!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\magenta{\colorbox{magenta!80}{\color{magenta!80}\textbf{1}}}

Zerlegung von: Elementfixierung mit fester Position\label{Tab1}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:appendrow} 
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\overbrace{}^{6* \binom{1}{1} red}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\overbrace{}^{ 3* \binom{1}{1} yellow}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\overbrace{}^{1* \binom{1}{1} green}} \\
\red & \red & \red & \red & \red & \red & \yellow & \yellow & \yellow & \green \\
\yellow & \yellow & \yellow & \green & \green & \blue & \green & \green & \blue & \blue \\ 
\green & \blue & \magenta & \blue & \magenta & \magenta & \blue & \magenta & \magenta & \magenta \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\underbrace{}{\binom{4}{2}}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\underbrace{}{\binom{3}{2}}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\underbrace{}_{\binom{3}{3}}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Rendering of my code]
Here I am using a colorboxed array with entries "1" of the same color (sorry for the dirty hack the boxes were too small if the cells were empty) to create towers of colored blocks. I would like to show how you can divide and conquer the problem of strategyrecognition by breaking down the problem using the binomialcoefficient property (n over k) = (n-1 over k-1) + (n-1 over k).

I would like the first under- and overbraces to span over the first 6 columns, then second braces to span over the next 3 columns and the last braces to span only over the last column.

So far if I tried to use \multicolumn with several of my color-commands, I always got a huge wall of compile errors. Could you tell me how to do what I intend to do please?

Answer (score 1):

Add suitable phantoms. With `expl3` we can achieve it with a less painful syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayoverbrace}{mm}
 {
  \multicolumn{#1}{c}
   {
    \overbrace
     {
      \hphantom
       {
        \begin{array}{*{#1}{c}}
        \red\prg_replicate:nn{#1-1}{& \red}
        \end{array}
       }
     }\sp{#2}
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayunderbrace}{mm}
 {
  \multicolumn{#1}{c}
   {
    \underbrace
     {
      \hphantom
       {
        \begin{array}{*{#1}{c}}
        \red\prg_replicate:nn{#1-1}{& \red}
        \end{array}
       }
     }\sb{#2}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\red{\colorbox{red!80}{\color{red!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\yellow{\colorbox{yellow!80}{\color{yellow!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\green{\colorbox{green!80}{\color{green!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\blue{\colorbox{blue!80}{\color{blue!80}\textbf{1}}} 
\newcommand\magenta{\colorbox{magenta!80}{\color{magenta!80}\textbf{1}}}

\begin{document}

Zerlegung von: Elementfixierung mit fester Position\label{Tab1}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:appendrow} 
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
\arrayoverbrace{6}{6* \binom{1}{1} \text{ red}}&
\arrayoverbrace{3}{3* \binom{1}{1} \text{ yellow}}&
\arrayoverbrace{1}{1* \binom{1}{1} \text{ green}} \\
\red & \red & \red & \red & \red & \red & \yellow & \yellow & \yellow & \green \\
\yellow & \yellow & \yellow & \green & \green & \blue & \green & \green & \blue & \blue \\ 
\green & \blue & \magenta & \blue & \magenta & \magenta & \blue & \magenta & \magenta & \magenta \\[-1ex]
\arrayunderbrace{6}{\binom{4}{2}}&
\arrayunderbrace{3}{\binom{3}{2}}&
\arrayunderbrace{1}{\binom{3}{3}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is wonderful.
Any idea why the last tower in the group of 6 and 3 each is more apart from the others? While this wouldn't matter for my thesis, it's still a bit displeasing visually.